# JPA Passing List with parameters

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

working on refactoring some code from a stream hitting a repository multiple times to simply passing the whole list of objects to the repo and it returning all rows back. I have three params I want to search for in a database and just return the entire row from the db. Here is my current setup:

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE as p WHERE p.id IN :personSearchParams AND s.firstName IN :personSearchParams AND s.lastName IN :personSearchParams")
    fun findByIdAndFirstNameAndLastName(@Param("personSearchParams") personSearchParams: List<PersonSearchParams>): List<Person>
```

My data object is:

```
data class personSearchParam (

    @NotBlank(message = "id must not be blank.")
    var id: String,

    @NotBlank(message = "firstName must not be blank.")
    var firstName: String,

    @NotBlank(message = "lastName must not be blank.")
    var lastName: String
)
```

But am receiving the following error: `Could not determine a type for class: com.person.entity.personSearchParam`

How can I able to pass the list of params and expect a list of entities back?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `personSearchParam` to `PersonSearchParam` and `@NotBlank` to `@field:NotBlank`.
Reference = https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets